# CLion воспроизведение звука

Tags: clion

пробую на простом примере:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "windows.h"
#include "mmsystem.h"

int main()
{
    PlaySound(TEXT("tet.wav"),NULL, SND_SYNC);
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

но выдаёт

> undefined reference to `__imp_PlaySoundA'

вроде нужен .lib насколько знаю, но как его подключить в CLion`e?

Comment: Пробовали в `CMakeLists.txt` добавить `target_link_libraries(цель бибилотека)` ?

Comment: Нет, с CMake к сожалению мне "незнакомец". Не могли-бы вы подробно объяснить как через него подключать?

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите использовать именно Clion то вам следует изучить cmake иначе под виндой только visual studio.

Вот русскоязычная [ссылка](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=CMake_Tutorial) на небольшой мануал.

Если в кратце то вам нужно:

```
find_package(libName REQUIRED)//найти нужную библиотеку
include_directories(${INCLUDE_DIRS})//добавить найденные инклуды которые хранятся в ${INCLUDE_DIRS}
target_link_libraries(test libName)//теперь осталось только подключить либу
```

Это общие действия. В зависимости от либы они могут отличаться так что настоятельна рекомендую изучить **cmake**.